# How to partition with multiple hard drives: 120 GB SSD + 1TB HDD?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

120GB SSD:

- 20GB for `/` - primary
- 100GB for `/var`

1TB HDD:

- 4GB for swap
- 96GB for `/home`

Is this correct way to do the partitioning?

Comment: What works best for what your trying to do!

Comment: What will the system be used for? 100GiB is way overkill for a desktop system. 96GB /home is too small for many. 4GB Swap may be too small for a suspend to disk.

Comment: System used for software development.